# In 1.0 we can get workflow action script paramater by getSetting. How about 2.0?

Tags: suitescript2.0

As per title, i wish to get the workflow action script parameter in 2.0.
I tried ScriptContext.getSetting('Script',parameter_id) in 2.0 but it doesn't work.
Please help! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the below code snippet, it returns the value of a script parameter for the currently executing script.

```
var scriptObj = runtime.getCurrentScript();
log.debug("Script parameter of custscript1: " + 
     scriptObj.getParameter({name: 'custscript1'}));
```

Let me know the output.